# Is it possible to analytically solve an equation that has a magnitude of a vector quartic?

Tags: vectors

So, given something like the following equation where boldface variables ${\bf a, b, c, d, e}$ are known vectors in $\mathbb{R^n}$ where n > 1, K is a known in $\mathbb{R}$, and trying to solve for x in $\mathbb{R}$:

$$ || {\bf a} x^4 + {\bf b} x^3 + {\bf c} x^2 + {\bf d} x + {\bf e} || = K $$

I know that a quartic can be solved analytically, but with the magnitude in there I'm not sure. Multiplying it out ${\bf z} \cdot {\bf z} = K^2$ would result in a degree 8 polynomial which could not be solved analytically. I'm just wondering if there is some way because of the magnitude operator there might be some way to avoid increasing the degree that way and thus solving it analytically.

Comment: What are $\mathbf a, \mathbf b$, etc.?

Comment: Am I to interpret $x^4$ as being the vector where each of its components are raised to the fourth power?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include the info about the variables, @muaddib x isn't a vector. a, b, c, d, e are vectors. Theophile a, b... are vectors, I added that to question now.

Comment: How do you expect to solve this when your vectors are all 1 dimensional, i.e. scalars? It's equivalent to solving a quartic equation, so it's unclear what you expect in general? You can definitely solve the multivariate case numerically using something like Newton iteration.

Comment: @AlexR. The vectors aren't one dimensional. a, b, c, d, e are 3 dimensional real vectors in this specific case. x and K are the only scalars in there.

Comment: @taotree: Yes, so what? Take $a=b=c=d=e=(1,0,0)$ which reduces it to a 1 dimensional case. It's still annoying. And given how well numerical solutions converge for these kinds of problems, there's no reason to try and find an analytical solution in the first place.

Comment: @AlexR. I'm aware that numerical solutions exist to solve this. I have reasons to want to do it analytically, that's why I'm asking if it's possible. The 1 dimensional case is a solveable quartic as you mention, but the multi-dimensional case I don't know, thus this question.

Comment: @AlexR. The way I interpret the question is that $a,b,c,d,e$ are given vectors in $\Bbb{R}^n$ (or some other normed space, but $\Bbb{R}^n$ is surely the most likely), $K$ is a known constant, and $x$ is the only unknown.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen that is correct. I apologize for not being clear, and I've edited the question to reflect that information. I'll get better at asking questions precisely. I appreciate your patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further reflection and comments, I think it's pretty clear the answer is no. It will one way or another result in a higher degree (> 4) polynomial which is known to be unsolvable analytically.